# 'show' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, show, mongodb-stitch

After successfully executing `mongod --version` command, when I tried running `show dbs` command to view database it is showing me the error:

> 'show' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

The result should be showing the list of databases.

Comment: `show` is a shell command, you should run it either in `mongo` or `mongosh` shell

Comment: Also, `mongod --versiom` doesn't necessarily mean that the database (eg `mongod` process) is running. You'll want to make sure that it is, then connect to it with one of the shells that @dododo mentioned. Notably the shells also support a `db.version()` command that you can use to confirm the version of the process you connect to as opposed to the version of the binaries located at the `mongod` path locally